# How to make Box-plots horizontal?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I have a few box-plots but they are really illegible due to their orientation being vertical - I would like to try making them horizontal. This is the code I have

```
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 30))
for num, name_df in enumerate(all_data.items(), start=1):
   name, df = name_df
   #df.T.boxplot(vert=False)
   plt.subplot(10,2,num)
   # plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
   df[top_10_columns[name]].boxplot()
   plt.title(name)
   plt.xticks(rotation=25)
```

[image]

Comment: try adding `vert=False` to the call to `boxplot()`

Comment: You would also benefit from [`plt.tight_layout()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html) in the end.